# Solr giving error 400 failed request

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm working on a project in which server uses Solr technology. I have implemented a feature in which data is being filtered.

```
<li (click)="filterByDate()">Sort by Date</li>

filterByDate() {
  this.searchdata.sort = 'last_modified desc';
  this.route.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: this.searchdata });
}
```

When I click on `Sort by Date` it throws this error, though this feature was working earlier:[image]

I'm not able to get how this error is happening. It would be great if someone can guide me to overcome this issue. Thanks.

Comment: So what is the value of the `start` parameter being sent to Solr?

Comment: @MatsLindh `start=0`

Comment: @MatsLindh, Can you help me with this error?

Comment: Well, Solr is complaining about it _not_ being 0. So check the actual Solr log for what it actually receives / parses and add it to the question.

Comment: @MatsLindh In which case it is complaining?

Comment: The error message literally is "'start' parameter can't be negative", so apparently you're sending a negative value for start somewhere - the question is where it's being introduced (and why, if you're not, Solr thinks you're sending a negative value.)